# FontAwesome Update - Old Icons to New

Tags: javascript, php, css, font-awesome

I have a large website that uses FontAwesome. Recently we upgraded from 4.6 I believe to the latest version.

After the upgrade all of our icons are broken. A lot of the far/fa not working but if I change them to fa-solid they work.

The issue is the site is incredibly large with a lot of files so it can multiple days going through all these files to correct the icons.

Has anyone got a quicker solution for this to make the latest font awesome work?

Icons are broken after an update to the latest version.

Comment: Check all file with php, and when you will find this string "/"fa" add after "-solid". And report all changes in a file for check if there are wrong cases.

Comment: Font Awesome says: "
We've included files to help make Font Awesome 6 easily backward compatible with older versions. Learn how you can easily get your Web Fonts or SVG project using v6 icons without touching a single element or pseudo-element CSS rule." See: [Backward Compatibility](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/whats-changed#backward-compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Yogi's comment of backwards compatibility saved me. Thanks bro

Comment: It is not advised to say "thank you" in comments, and most definitely not in answers.